# Update table with new value for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a column (type of `datetime`) in the top 1000 rows my table. However the catch is with each additional row I must increment the `GETDATE()` by 1 second... something like `DATEADD(ss,1,GETDATE())`

The only way I know how to do this is something like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET columnname = CASE id
                        WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(ss,1,GETDATE())
                        WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(ss,2,GETDATE())
                        ...
                    END
```

Obviously this is not plausible. Any ideas?

Comment: You could write a custom function that increments a getdate value

Comment: @JimSosa Ya that's what i am thinking... I am doing this within SSIS so it would be easy to do so. Just wanted to see if there was a cool little trick where I could do it in a query

Comment: Have you tried DateAdd(ss, id, getDate()).  Assuming your ids are all increments of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your ID is like, and I'm assuming you have at least SQL Server 2008 or else ROW_NUMBER() won't work.

Note: I did top 2 to show you that you that the top works. You can change it to top 1000 for your actual query.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID int, columnName DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @table(ID)
    VALUES(1),(2),(3);

UPDATE @table
SET columnName =  DATEADD(SECOND,B.row_num,GETDATE())
FROM @table A
INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT TOP 2 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) row_num
            FROM @table
            ORDER BY ID
            ) B
ON A.ID = B.ID


SELECT *
FROM @table
```

Results:

```
ID          columnName
----------- -----------------------
1           2015-03-31 13:11:59.760
2           2015-03-31 13:12:00.760
3           NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `id` rather than a constant?

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET columnname = DATEADD(second, id, GETDATE() )
   WHERE id <= 1000;
```

If you want the first 1000 rows (by `id`), but the `id` has gaps or other problems, then you can use a `CTE`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from tablename
     )
update toupdate
     set columnname = dateadd(second, seqnum, getdate())
     where seqnum <= 1000;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't make explicit the SQL Server version you're using, so I will assume SQL Server 2005 or above. I believe the **WAITFOR DELAY** command would be a good option to keep adding 1 second to each rows of the datetime column.

See this example:

```
-- Create temp table
CREATE TABLE #Client  
( 
    RecordID int identity(1,1),
    [Name] nvarchar(100) not null,
    PurchaseDate datetime null
)

-- Fill in temp table with example values
INSERT INTO #Client
VALUES ( 'Jhon', NULL)

INSERT INTO #Client
VALUES ( 'Martha', NULL)

INSERT INTO #Client
VALUES ( 'Jimmy', NULL)


-- Create local variables
DECLARE @currentRecordId int, 
        @currentName nvarchar(100)

-- Create cursor
DECLARE ClientsCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  RecordID,
        [Name]
FROM    #Client

OPEN ClientsCursor

FETCH FROM ClientsCursor INTO @currentRecordId, @currentName

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    UPDATE  #Client
    SET     PurchaseDate = DATEADD(ss,1,GETDATE())
    WHERE   RecordID = @currentRecordId
    AND     [Name] = @currentName

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.000'

    FETCH NEXT FROM ClientsCursor INTO @currentRecordId, @currentName

END

CLOSE ClientsCursor;
DEALLOCATE ClientsCursor;

SELECT *
FROM   #Client
```

And here's the result:

```
1   Jhon    2015-03-31 15:20:04.477
2   Martha  2015-03-31 15:20:05.473
3   Jimmy   2015-03-31 15:20:06.470
```

Hope you find this answer helpful

Comment: There is no need to use a cursor for an update like this. Since this is supposed to update the "first" 1,000 rows your code would take 1,000 seconds to run. That is an update that should take a fraction of a second extended into more than 16 minutes.

Answer (score -2):

This should be what you need (at least a guidline)

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE ADDTIME()

BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT Default 1 ;
  simple_loop: LOOP         
     UPDATE tablename SET columnname = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL i SECOND) where rownumber = i
     SET i=i+1;
     IF i=1001 THEN
        LEAVE simple_loop;
     END IF;
  END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$
```

To call that stored procedure use

CALL `ADDTIME`()

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It's a mysql Loop statement.  He did not specify what database he was using that is why I said it was a guideline.

Comment: I do apologize. Did not see that.

Comment: No worries. The tag is in a small font. And I was really was wondering what language it is. I've only used T-SQL so thanks for letting me know it's MySQL! It has a very interesting loop syntax.